# nservicebus startup error

Tags: c#, nservicebus, esb, cqrs

I'm trying to get up and running with my NServiceBus setup.

I'm basically trying to copy some of the AsyncPages sample project.

In my CommandServer project I have the following config:

```
 <MsmqTransportConfig
    InputQueue="SonatribeInputQueue"
    ErrorQueue="error"
    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
    MaxRetries="5"
/>
```

I have the following message endpoint:

```
public class MessageEndpoint : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Perform initialization logic.
        /// </summary>
        public void Init()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Configuring persistence...");
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "CommandServer.*.dll")));
            Configure.With()
                .CastleWindsorBuilder(container).BinarySerializer();
        }
    }
```

in my Messages project I have the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Command : IMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And back in the CommandServer project i have the corresponding CommandHandler:

```
public class CommandMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<Command>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Handle(Command message)
    {
        Logger.Info(string.Format("Server 1 received Command with Id {0}.", message.Id));
    }

    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CommandMessageHandler));
}
```

no, aside from the windsor stuff - which doesn't affect this at all - there is nothing different from the async project to this. yet whenever i run the CommandServer I get the following output:

```
Configuring eventstore persistence...

2011-07-12 16:33:32,524 [1] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null
)> - LocalAddress property of UnicastBusConfig not found. Using InputQueue prope
rty of MsmqTransportConfig instead. This will not be supported in the next versi
on.
2011-07-12 16:33:32,702 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Hosting.Roles.RoleManager [(null)]
 <(null)> - Role NServiceBus.AsA_Server configured
2011-07-12 16:33:32,750 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Host [(null)] <(null)> - Going to
activate profile: NServiceBus.Lite, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=n
eutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2011-07-12 16:33:35,749 [1] FATAL NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost [(null)] <(nul
l)> - System.InvalidOperationException: No destination could be found for messag
e type Messages.Command. Check the <MessageEndpointMapping> section of the confi
guration of this endpoint for an entry either for this specific message type or
for its assembly.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Subscribe(Type messageType, Predicate`1 con
dition) in c:\Dev\NServiceBus\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
 405
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.Subscribe(Type messageType) in c:\Dev\NServ
iceBus\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 353
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.PerformAutoSubcribe() in c:\Dev\NServiceBus
\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 754
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start(Action star
tupAction) in c:\Dev\NServiceBus\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:l
ine 739
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start() in c:\Dev
\NServiceBus\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 702
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() in c:\Dev\NServiceBus\src\hosting\
NServiceBus.Hosting\GenericHost.cs:line 99
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you're using NServiceBus 3.0 already?  It hasn't been released yet.  It looks like you're trying to use 3.0 with a 2.5-style config.  Does it do the same thing with 2.5?

Comment: Needed to compile it with the latest windsor...

Comment: If think I'll try and recompile it tomorrow with the older nsb dlls.

Comment: If it's the Windsor problem you're trying to get around, you can try the Core Only distribution of 2.5, as described at http://www.nservicebus.com/Downloads.aspx under "Problems with merged assemblies?"

Comment: do you not have a <MessageEndpointMapping> section or are did you not include it in the sample?

Comment: there isn't one on the server in the supplied sample?

Comment: I am getting this from: https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/Samples/AsyncPages/Server

Comment: What a waste of a day!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically stemmed from me mixing up v3 with v2.5 stuff and getting in a complete tail spin.

The problem coming from the fact that the 2.5 download did not build form the NSB site. Udi has now updated the rev in the 2.5 github branch and i am going to try with that to get the latest caste working so i can skip using 3.0 until it is stable enough.

in other words - this should have just worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find that you are missing the  MessageEndpointMapping section

The sample that you are using does not do any Bus.Send and therefore does not need the message mapping section.

the only thing that the handler in that [sample](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/Samples/AsyncPages/Server/CommandMessageHandler.cs) is a Bus.Return

The other option is to use Bus.Send with a queue name where you intend the message to end up at.

Comment: auto subscriptions seem to be the problem in the error output you might notice  "NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.PerformAutoSubcribe()" try adding .BinarySerializer().UnicastBus().DoNotAutoSubscribe(); to your init method.